# How to replace Gutenberg block content with JavaScript, without saving it to the server?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, dispatch

I'm using this function to update the post content in the Gutenberg editor. (It's triggered when the author clicks a button in a custom sidebar.) It replaces all of the instances of a custom anchor link which is part of a HTML snippet pasted into the editor. This works perfectly.

However, the use of `wp.data.dispatch` saves the changes to the server immediately. I'd prefer it if the changes were just written to the editor, and only saved when the author clicks the save/publish button.

Is there a solution for this?

```
const reworkFootnotes = () => {
    const blocks = wp.data.select('core/block-editor').getBlocks();
    const pattern = /<a href=['"]#end[0-9]+['"]>([0-9]+)<\/a>/gi;
    blocks.forEach(block => {
        if (!!block.attributes.content && !!block.attributes.content.length) {
            const matches = block.attributes.content.match(pattern);
            if (!!matches) {
                wp.data.dispatch('core/editor').updateBlockAttributes(block.clientId, {
                    content: block.attributes.content.replaceAll(
                        pattern,
                        function (match, contents) {
                            return `[[${contents}]]`;
                        }
                    ),
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A brainstorm before lunch. The code in this example *doesn't* save the post, so it works correctly.